# How to transfer HubSpot blog to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, hubspot

I tried the quick and easy route by just getting the rss.xml file from my HubSpot blog, and than importing that through a WordPress Plugin WP All Import. It gets all the titles and some pictures but a lot of content is missing from each post.

I also exported all the html of each blog post off of hubspot, but hubspot doesn't offer any guidance as to how to map that over to WordPress posts. it seems like the process is really complicated if you want to get everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using an RSS Importer:

1. Log in to your Hubspot blog.
2. click on the RSS link.
3. Look at the URL in the browser. If it shows a maxcount (e.g. maxcount=25), change it to a large number so all of your posts are shown.
4. Copy all of the text and paste it into a text file and save it.
5. Log in to your WordPress blog.
6. Go to Tools > Import Choose RSS import. If you haven't installed this already then click on the install button.
7. Upload your text file.
8. Press the OK button to complete the import.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little hack that lets you generate a CSV using a coded HubSpot blog listing template. The full instructions can be found here: https://www.bluleadz.com/blog/how-to-export-a-hubspot-blog

tldr: copy and paste this code into a coded blog template:

```
{% if is_listing_view %}
"post_title","post_body","featured_image","author","topics",
{% for content in contents %}
"{{ content.name|forceescape|replace('
','') }}","{{ content.post_body|forceescape|replace('
','') }}","{{ content.featured_image|forceescape|replace('
','') }}","{{ content.author_name|forceescape|replace('
','') }}","{{ content.topic_list|forceescape|replace('
','') }}"{% endfor %}{% endif %}
```

change your blog listing content settings to display 1,000 posts and preview the new template to get all the data. Finally, save the preview html file and change the file extension to `.csv`